# is the newline "\n" 2 characters or 1 character

Tags: python, io

So i have a file.txt:

```
>>012345
>> (new line)
```

when I call:

```
b=a.read(7)
print b
```

this will give me

```
 012345
 (with a newline here)
```

So I see that it has read the next 7 characters, counting the "\n" as a single character.
But when I use seek, it seems that it treats "\n" as two characters:

```
position = a.seek(-2,2)
b=a.read(1)
print b
```

this prints a new blank line instead of 5.

Do these 2 methods treat "`\n`" differently?

Comment: It depends if the platform is Linux, or Windows, or MacOSX

Comment: can you clarify this question is about opening files not just string? Your title is confusing search engines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python opens files in *text mode* by default. Files open in text mode have platform-native newline conventions translated to `\n` automatically.

You opened a file using the `\r\n` newline convention, on Windows most probably.

Open the file in binary mode if you do not want this translation to take place. See the documentation of the [`open()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) for more details:

> The default is to use text mode, which may convert `'\n'` characters to a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading. Thus, when opening a binary file, you should append `'b'` to the mode value to open the file in binary mode, which will improve portability.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to deal with this yourself. Python comes with batteries included. :-)

If the newlines bother you, just `read()` the whole file and use the [`splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) method for strings;

```
In [21]: test = 'foo \nbar bla\n baz\r\n'

In [22]: test.splitlines()
Out[22]: ['foo ', 'bar bla', ' baz']
```

Note that this only removes whitespace at the end of lines.